# Unable to Call Controller in Ajax call

Tags: ajax

I want to destroy the session when the user clicks the fa-fa-close icon.

I tried creating an ajax call and destroying the session.

But when I call the ajax method this method throws an error.

Can anyone help why this has happened?

[image]

[image]

Comment: 1- Never user /api/sitecore
2- RenderingContext will be  null in ajax request

Comment: Then How I call my controller back ?

Comment: There is no need to use renderingcontext ,you can use Sitecore.Contexxt.Item or  GetItem , also configure a seperate  route , dont use /api/sitecore , it will  break in your CD server

Comment: Instead of screenshot's, can you paste your code, and error messages as code blocks?  This will allow others to search on similar keywords to find this post.  Search can't read text in images.

Answer (score 1):

`Sitecore.Context.Item` would be null when you will call a method through ajax call in the view as per my understanding.
You need to provide `Sitecore.Context.Item` at the view level(.cshtml file). If you need item id in the method then you can pass the code below in the parameters in ajax call and get it on the method and get the item based on pass item id.

```
@Sitecore.Context.Item.ID
```

I had the same problem `Sitecore.Context.Item` value was null when calling through ajax call.

Hope it helps !!

Answer (score 0):

Use **RenderingContext.CurrentOrNull** if you need to test for the existence of the rendering context rather than **RenderingContext.Current**.  If you have no current rendering context (ie an ajax call) then attempts to read **RenderingContext.Current** throw an exception.  I know you're doing a null check on it, but if it is null it will throw an exception when reading it, just one of those Sitecore oddities.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error, the controller is getting called but since the RenderingContext is null the error is being thrown. The RenderingContext is always null in AJAX call.

Use:

```
public Item ContextItem = Sitecore.Context.Item;
```

That should solve your issue. Let me know in case you need any further help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear the session, use the following generic method and destroy the value from the session.

```
public static void Remove(string key)
        {
            var session = HttpContext.Current?.Session;
            if (null != session && session[key] != null)
            {
                session[key] = null;
            }
        }
```

*Sitecore.Context.Item* and *RenderingContext* will always be null when you try to invoke from the API context.